# django rest angular login

Tags: django, angularjs, django-rest-framework

I am looking to find the best way to handle logging in users with django rest and angular.  Currently I am doing this in the controller,

```
$http.post('accounts/login/', $scope.user).then(function(response){
```

and this is the view,

```
def login(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        username = data['username']
        password = data['password']
        //rest of login function
```

It works, but it seems like there is a best practice I am not following here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only 'better' practice that I can think of, would be:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view(['POST'])
def login(request):
    data = request.DATA
    # authenticate using data dict
    return Response({'status': 'ok'})
```

This way you don't need to decode json manually and you restrict view to POST only, so no need to check the request method.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are lot's of better solutions. What you're using is just fine, but not for developing more complicated projects. Let me give you a tour on this:

> The solution is using Rest APIs in django. There are many great libraries to provide rest api system with django, but I recommend using django-rest-framework. 
>    (At least i made a lot of projects with it:)

To install it in your project follow guide on 
[installing django rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

And to provide login api for angular, you should use one of authentication systems provided with this library, or create your own authentication system.
If you are using angular inside django template engine, i recommend SessionAuthentication, if not use BasicAuthentication instead (or if you want a better solution use 3rd party apps like jwt or oauth. it's all your decision based on your project).

Basically what these authentication systems do is that they check if credentials are provided in requests or not. for example if you are using basicAuthentication, all your requests should contain an `Authorization: token <token>` header with them (this is the part that angular `$http` method should put this header on each request.)

Also you should create some APIs to get, verify and refresh tokens receiving from server. I recommend read this section [adding TokenAuthentication with django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication).

feel free to ask anything in comments. I'll be glad if i could help you on this road.